# Symfony - suppress logging for specific endpoint

Tags: php, symfony, logging, request, symfony4

I have specific endpoint where I put an empty response:

```
/**
 * @Route("/ping", name="ping")
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function gcpPingAction(): JsonResponse
{
    return $this->json([], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

In my log I get:

[image]

Is it possible to suppress somehow the logging of this endpoint that is hit? Just for that specific endpoint..

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_exclude_http_codes.html), you should be able to do it like so.

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            # ...
            type: fingers_crossed
            handler: ...
            excluded_http_codes: [{ 200: ['^/ping$'] }]
```

Or like so

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            # ...
            type: fingers_crossed
            handler: ...
            excluded_http_codes:
                - urls:
                    - '^/ping$'
```

However, I did not test it.